# mean and variance of a dataset

Tags: variance, mean

I have a simple question. Please see the below screenshot :
[image]

It is from a midterm exam from a university : [https://cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE555/exams/midterm-solution-2006.pdf](https://cedar.buffalo.edu/%7Esrihari/CSE555/exams/midterm-solution-2006.pdf)
My questions is how the means are postive ? I am asking because the class samples are all negative so I would expect that the mean is also negative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo in the solution.

The author corrects it by correctly computing the Bayes discriminant in the next step.